# Adding a content background with padding in 3 column layout

Tags: css

I need to have a 3 column layout where the content should have a background padded with 20px all around. However if its content is big, it should get higher.

I found [this nice implementation](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Jb2bm/) of 3 column layout I am using, but I am unable to add what I need. You can see the desired target image below.

[image: Mock of desired goal]

It seems that the main problem is to get the height to behave appropriately as I got the padding on top, right and left right, but I have no idea what to do with the height.

So far I tried changing height to 100%, but then my scroll is messed up.

I also tried absolute positioning but could not get it to work properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So basically you want this white thing to be all over?

Comment: What name should I use instead?

Comment: Yes Lipis, but with the padding as described.

Comment: I think 3 column layout is more descriptive than holy grail :)

Comment: It's still the question is a bit broad.. it depends on if you want to have the scroll inside the content only when too much text or for the whole page? you have to be a bit more specific I think..

Comment: I want the scroll to be on the body, just as it works now.